# Bad Gateway with NGINX as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I've been trying to redirect traffic from https://server:443 to internally http://server:8088 using NGINX as a reverse proxy, I can see my service on 8088 is running since I can access to it, by the time I try to access it from https and port 443 it gives me a 502 bad gateway error. The service Im running is Apache Superset.

I have already created my cert.pem and key.pem files. Already tried several combinations on /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf on the location section but no luck so far.

```
server {
      listen      443 http2 ssl;
      server_name localhost;

     ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/key.pem;

      location / {
        add_header           Front-End-Https    on;
        add_header  Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2592000; includeSubdomains";
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8088;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Connection      "";
      }
}
```

I'd expect to hit https://server:443 and it will display my service which is running at http://server:8088.